# Is there a way to quickly initialize an array with a sequence of values in Ada?

Tags: ada

For instance if I want to initialize an array of elements like so:

```
someArray : array(1..10) of Integer := (2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20);
```

Is there a short-hand way or some mechanism to do this quicker?

Matlab and python has for example the `linspace` function that returns a sequence of equally spaced numbers. Is there a similar functionality for Ada that works for any array type of any length?

I can make a generic function to do this, but that would require separate initialization for each individual array type and that seems a bit cumbersome for a function that will essentially be used once for each array type.

Comment: These days I consider code generation for this kind of problem. Or even as blunt as having a shell command incantation generating the line, documented appropriately.

Comment: `echo {2..20..2} | sed "s/ /,/g"`, copy-paste the output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ada 2022 (e.g. GCC 12 with `-gnat2022`) allows

```ada
package Aggregates is

   type A is array (Integer range <>) of Integer;

   V : A := (for J in 1 .. 10 => J * 2);

end Aggregates;
```

Comment: See also [_Iterated Component Association_](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/whats-new-in-ada-2022/chapters/array_aggregates.html#iterated-component-association).

Comment: I would like to point out that when the document at that link says that use of parens round array aggregates is obsolescent this is an AdaCore position, not justified by the ARM (i.e. it’s not in Annex J). It’s extremely annoying for anyone trying to develop for people who may not be able to use the latest compiler (/rant)

Comment: Nice that this feature is finally here! Kinda disappointing that it took this long for such a basic (in my opinion) feature...